# ListView of available Bluetooth device goes blank while rotating the screen

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I have one activity in which I scan the Bluetooth devices an put in a list view. when I scan the devices display well but when I rotate the screen (portrait <-> landscape) the list view goes Blank.

I have implemented the onSaveInstanceState method but I don't realy know what to save in the outState.put...

```java
 // implement the broadcast reciever for the BT scanning
    private final BroadcastReceiver btScanBrcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mBTDevices.add(device);
                availableDevicesList = new AvailableDevicesList(context, R.layout.device_list_view, mBTDevices);

                lv_list_devices.setAdapter(availableDevicesList);
            }

        }
    };
```

in the onCreate method

```java
//perform action when clicking on device scaning
        scan_dv_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // check if the scan in in process
                if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                    // cancel the scanning
                    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                    // for version greater than Lolipop
                    checkBTPermission();

                    // restart it
                    btAdapter.startDiscovery();

                    // register the Broadcast receiver
                    IntentFilter IntentfindDv = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    registerReceiver(btScanBrcastReceiver, IntentfindDv);
                }
                if(!btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                    //// for version greater than Lolipop
                    checkBTPermission();

                    // start the scanning
                    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    // register the Broadcast receiver
                    IntentFilter IntentfindDv = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                    registerReceiver(btScanBrcastReceiver, IntentfindDv);

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your activity is recreating when you change the orientation(portrait <-> landscape). If you don't want to refresh the UI when rotating the screen,please use the following at your manifest file,

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"            
android:configChanges="orientation">
```

If you want to avoid activity recreation on multiple activities, please check below,

> android:configChanges 
>   Lists configuration changes that the activity
>   will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the
>   activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a
>   configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being
>   restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its
>   onConfigurationChanged() method is called.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element

```
  android:configChanges=["mcc", "mnc", "locale",
                         "touchscreen", "keyboard", "keyboardHidden",
                         "navigation", "screenLayout", "fontScale",
                         "uiMode", "orientation", "density",
                         "screenSize", "smallestScreenSize"]
```

Comment: I used android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  and it work thank you